# Find multiplicative inverse polynomial if $gcd(f,g) \neq 1$

Tags: number-theory

I'm going to find multiplicative inverse of polynomial $P(x)$ in the polynomial field $F_{5}/f(x)$.

I've tried the Extended Euclidean Algorithm($f*X+p*Y = gcd(f,p) =1$), but what should i do if $gcd(f,g)$ doesn't equal $1$.

I have these polynomials: $P(x)=x^8+2x^7+4x^6+2x^5+3x^4+4x^3+x^2+x+1$

$F(x)=x^5+x^4+3x^3+2x^2+3x+2$ .

And i found that:  $gcd(F,G)=x^2+x+2$

and then, $gcd(F,G)=(x^2+x+2)=F(4x^2+2x+1)+P(x^5+4x^4+2x^3+x^2+2x+3)$; to find the inverse, should i divide them by $x^2+x+2$? Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: If the gcd is not 1, then the polynomials are zerodivisors. Inverses do not exist.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\ gg'\equiv 1\pmod f\,\Rightarrow\,  \color{#0a0}gg'\!+\color{#0a0}fh = \color{#c00}{\bf 1}\ $ so $\ d\mid \color{#0a0}{g,f} \,\Rightarrow\, d\mid\color{#c00}{\bf 1}\ $ in $\Bbb F_5[x]\,\Rightarrow\, \deg d = 0$

Comment: Dubuqu Could you explain more? What is $d$

Comment: @nooogii $\ d\mid \color{#0a0}{g,f}$ means $d$ is some common divisor of $\color{#0a0}{g,f}\ \ $